# Probability interval and sorting a graph?

Tags: math, probability

When I have a graph with weights and a random generator how can I select some edges more desirable? I have a constraint of x weight and I need a formula that includes x weight and let me choose the next edge and so on. For example I have 4 edges with weight 5,10,15,20. How can I make the edge with weight 5 more desirable with a random generator but also when I have already choose edge 5 I need not choose edge with weight 20 because it exceeds my constraint.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, can you be more specific? This belongs to math.stackexchange.com anyways =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining the probability that one particular edge be selected as:

```
  P(select_this_edge) = (x - Weight_of_this_edge) / x
```

This will make edges with a low weight more likely to be selected, and edges with a weight bigger than the "constraint", x, impossible to select.

Assuming that the RNG (random number generator) produces values between 0 and 1, the process to decide if a given edge should be selected is to draw a random number and see if it is less or equal to the probability as computed in the formula.

Depending on you specific needs, you could alter the formula slightly, for example by introducing a small factor that would prevent an edge with weight 0 to be systematically selected (by introducing a residual chance that it wouldn't be selected),  and conversely to prevent edges with a higher than "constraint" x edge value of never being selected.

Now... the above discusses the way of assigning probability to decide **if a *given* edge should be selected**.  This is quite sufficient if indeed the program logic has a way of picking individual edges and simply asks itself the simple question "Should this particular  edge be selected?".  However the program logic may have come up with a list of edges (which could be the complete collection of edges) and want to answer a more complicated question: "Of these n edges which one should I select ?".
I was about to explain how to go about this 2nd type of problem, but in reading -between the lines- of the various comments, I think I understand better the problem at hand...

---

**Edit** (after various clarifications in comments)
As suspected, the underlying problem is that **of an *optimization* problem rather than one of *probability*** (although in this instance, probabilities are used to direct the search into the solution space in a stochastic fashion).
Specifically, the problem is one of the many variations on the [**Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem)

Without knowing details of what specific parameters (or combination thereof) we are trying to optimize, I can only speak in broad terms, trying to answer one of the questions of the OP:
**Is is ok to combine the probability associated with Weight with the probability associated with distance ?**

In a nutshell, **yes** it is.  A plain multiplication may do the trick, although I would like to suggest a formula akin to the following:

```
P(e) = Kw * Pw(e) + Kd Pd(e) + some_random_term
Where 
   P(e) is the probability of picking edge e, "all things considered"
   Kw and Kd are constant parameters which can be used to tweak the algorithm
   Pw(e) is the probability of picking egde e, with consideration to the Weight
   Pd(e) is the probability of picking egde e, with consideration to the Distance
   some_random_term is used to soften the algorithm in its tendency to favor too
      much high probability edges resulting in allowing the search process to get
      stuck in local minima.
      Rather than a added term, this can also be performed by a simple function
      which prevents the probability to be less than say 0.05 or more than say
      0.95.  A fancier sigmoid function may also do the trick.
```

Comment: Does it help when I've the lower bound of a weight? The problem is I need to select as many edges as possible?

Comment: @Chiyou, if you must select as many edges as possible, then you must not choose randomly between all available edges. If you must choose randomly between all available edges, then you must not select as many as possible. Your requirements are in conflict.

Comment: @Beta: not as many as possible but it should maximize 1 or 2 variables. It's also that I've a distance and a weight graph? I already have the probabilities for the distance graph (shortest distance is desireable). When I apply your formula can I add this to my probabilities? I'm not sure if there is an effect at all on choosing the edge?

Comment: @Chiyou: see my edits.  I'm trying to understand the problem your are trying to solve.  We can then zero on a method to solve the problem.  As hinted, there may be no need to assign probabilities to the edges.

Comment: @mjv: yes this is close but I need probabilities because it's a heuristic. I don't care if the solution is working because I also optimize the distance length (tsp) and I use many iterations with many small changes so I'm mosty likely sure to find a working solution. My problem is when I mulitply the distance p(x) with the weight p(x) it can work or not? I didn't tried it?!

Comment: @Chiyou the question to you is `What are your trying to optimize?`  Is it... the maximum weight visited? ... the minimum distance traveled? ...  Some ratio of weight / distance? ... the maximum number of edges visited? etc.   The other question is `Is the graph fully connected?` and finally `What's the general structure of the heuristic-based optimization process?`

Comment: Hmm, english isn't my native language but I try to optimize both i.e. a ratio but I'm happy if my solutions finds a good tour within the capacity constraints. I've also lower bound of both because I have bin-packing AND minimum spanning tree. The other things is complicated to explain and also do you really need it to help me? Capacited vehicel routing problem is well know and when I have a graph with probabilities it should be enough information? Graph isn't sparse. It's fully connected (n^2-(n-1)).

Comment: @Chiyou.   See edits.  In a nutshell, yes the probabilities associated with individual parameters of the problem may be combined, numerically, in various fashion.

Comment: Thanks: I think adding the probabilities makes more sense: mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56503.html.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "more desirable". I also don't really understand what you mean by "I have a constraint of x weight". But in general, you could create an array probabilities which stores the probability of choosing the ith edge at position i. Then you generate a random number between 0 and 1 and iterate through the Array. If the number is smaller than the probability at the current position, we take that edge. Otherwise, we subtract the current probability from the number and move on to the next position. So in pseudocode, it looks like this:

```
x = random([0.0, 1.0])
for i in 0..n
  if x < probabilities[i]
    choose(i)
    break
  else
    x -= probabilities[i]
  end
end
```

If you have many edges, you can also make this more efficient by storing the sum of the probabilities of the edges from 0 to i at position i in an array probability_sums and then do a binary search for x in that array and choose the edge at that position.

Comment: Can I sum probabilities from different graphs? I've a distance graph and a weight graph I want to find the capacitated routin vehicle path from edges?